# Why does tidy(model) return the same results for each site (factor) despite using group_by(site)?

Tags: r, group-by, extract, lm, tidy

I am new to RStudio and posting in stack, but your questions and answers have helped my immensely so far - thank you!

I am conducting simple linear regressions to detect significant changes in a health index over time by site, and wish to extract the results of each model to a csv file. Here is a sample of my data:

```
                 Site Date BHMmetal.score
1      Hobsonville  2000         -0.125
2      Hobsonville  2001         -0.092
3      Hobsonville  2002         -0.093
4      Hobsonville  2003         -0.123
5      Hobsonville  2004         -0.104
6      Hobsonville  2005         -0.102
7      Hobsonville  2006         -0.106
8      Hobsonville  2007         -0.101
9      Hobsonville  2008         -0.125
10     Hobsonville  2009         -0.105
11     Hobsonville  2010         -0.117
12     Hobsonville  2011         -0.157
13     Hobsonville  2012         -0.111
14     Hobsonville  2013         -0.098
15     Hobsonville  2014         -0.093
16     Hobsonville  2015         -0.087
17     Hobsonville  2016         -0.096
18     Hobsonville  2017         -0.104
19     Hobsonville  2018         -0.139
20  Henderson Creek 2000         -0.047
21  Henderson Creek 2001         -0.048
22  Henderson Creek 2002         -0.059
23  Henderson Creek 2003         -0.062
24  Henderson Creek 2004         -0.055
25  Henderson Creek 2005         -0.079
26  Henderson Creek 2006         -0.040
27  Henderson Creek 2007         -0.058
28  Henderson Creek 2008         -0.072
29  Henderson Creek 2009         -0.068
30  Henderson Creek 2015         -0.067
31  Henderson Creek 2016         -0.084
32       Meola Reef 2000         -0.103
33       Meola Reef 2001         -0.100
34       Meola Reef 2002         -0.102
35       Meola Reef 2003         -0.120
36       Meola Reef 2004         -0.094
37       Meola Reef 2005         -0.082
38       Meola Reef 2006         -0.100
39       Meola Reef 2007         -0.109
40       Meola Reef 2008         -0.083
41       Meola Reef 2009         -0.048
42       Meola Reef 2015         -0.031
43       Meola Reef 2016         -0.031
44        Shoal Bay 2000         -0.081
45        Shoal Bay 2001         -0.119
46        Shoal Bay 2002         -0.120
47        Shoal Bay 2003         -0.131
48        Shoal Bay 2004         -0.098
49        Shoal Bay 2005         -0.127
50        Shoal Bay 2006         -0.118
51        Shoal Bay 2007         -0.119
52        Shoal Bay 2008         -0.125
53        Shoal Bay 2009         -0.099
54        Shoal Bay 2010         -0.083
55        Shoal Bay 2011         -0.101
56        Shoal Bay 2012         -0.094
57        Shoal Bay 2013         -0.084
58       Whau River 2000         -0.089
59       Whau River 2001         -0.065
60       Whau River 2002         -0.070
61       Whau River 2003         -0.089
62       Whau River 2004         -0.093
63       Whau River 2005         -0.117
64       Whau River 2006         -0.127
65       Whau River 2007         -0.142
66       Whau River 2008         -0.124
67       Whau River 2009         -0.130
68       Whau River 2010         -0.092
69       Whau River 2011         -0.120
70       Whau River 2012         -0.083
71       Whau River 2013         -0.101
72       Whau River 2014         -0.112
73       Whau River 2015         -0.060
74       Whau River 2016         -0.074
75       Whau River 2017         -0.064
76       Whau River 2018         -0.102
77     Kaipara Bank 2015         -0.087
78     Kaipara Bank 2017         -0.051
79     Kaipara Bank 2009         -0.142
80     Kaipara Bank 2010         -0.119
81     Kaipara Bank 2011         -0.137
82     Kaipara Bank 2012         -0.120
83     Kaipara Bank 2013         -0.107
84     Kaipara Bank 2014         -0.106
85     Kaipara Bank 2018         -0.040
86     Kaipara Bank 2016         -0.098
87    Kakarai Flats 2015         -0.134
88    Kakarai Flats 2017         -0.095
89    Kakarai Flats 2009         -0.108
90    Kakarai Flats 2010         -0.142
91    Kakarai Flats 2011         -0.134
92    Kakarai Flats 2012         -0.183
93    Kakarai Flats 2013         -0.134
94    Kakarai Flats 2014         -0.117
95    Kakarai Flats 2018         -0.118
96    Kakarai Flats 2016         -0.100
97    Ngapuke Creek 2015         -0.167
98    Ngapuke Creek 2017         -0.154
99    Ngapuke Creek 2009         -0.187
100   Ngapuke Creek 2010         -0.218
101   Ngapuke Creek 2011         -0.172
102   Ngapuke Creek 2012         -0.199
103   Ngapuke Creek 2013         -0.164
104   Ngapuke Creek 2014         -0.153
105   Ngapuke Creek 2018         -0.131
106   Ngapuke Creek 2016         -0.170
107      Cowans Bay 1994          0.009
108      Cowans Bay 1995          0.023
109      Cowans Bay 1996          0.010
110      Cowans Bay 1997          0.004
111      Cowans Bay 1998          0.034
112      Cowans Bay 1999          0.044
113      Cowans Bay 2000          0.059
114      Cowans Bay 2001          0.022
115      Cowans Bay 2002          0.066
116      Cowans Bay 2003          0.004
117      Cowans Bay 2004         -0.025
118      Cowans Bay 2005         -0.004
119      Cowans Bay 2006          0.017
120      Cowans Bay 2007          0.019
121      Cowans Bay 2008          0.050
122      Cowans Bay 2009          0.008
123      Cowans Bay 2010          0.014
124      Cowans Bay 2016          0.011
125      Cowans Bay 2017          0.033
126     Dyers Creek 2005         -0.084
127     Dyers Creek 2006         -0.060
128     Dyers Creek 2007         -0.085
129     Dyers Creek 2008         -0.083
130     Dyers Creek 2009         -0.076
131     Dyers Creek 2010         -0.088
132     Dyers Creek 2011         -0.070
133     Dyers Creek 2012         -0.050
134     Dyers Creek 2013         -0.060
135     Dyers Creek 2014         -0.069
136     Dyers Creek 2015         -0.045
137     Dyers Creek 2017         -0.037
138     Dyers Creek 2018         -0.077
139     Dyers Creek 2016         -0.025
```

I first used this approach to produce the `lm` for each site:

```
linear.models <- with(annual.df.subset,
                     by(annual.df.subset,Site,
                       function(x)lm(BHMmetal.score~Date, data=x)))
output <- sapply(linear.models,coef)
```

But couldn't figure out how to extract anything other than the coefficients (I am also wanting the Std. error, t and p values). This approach results in different coefficient values for each site.

I have since come across this approach:

```
linear.models2 <- annual.subset %>%
                      group_by(Site) %>%
                         do(model = lm(BHMmetal.score~Date, data=annual.df.subset)) %>%
                          tidy(model)
```

which is more intuitive to me and seems as though it will allow me to do more with the individual models. However, the values for each of the model components are the same for every site, which possibly suggests the `tidy` function is only being applied to the model of the final site?

I do not understand why this second approach doesn't work, and would really appreciate any feedback.

Additionally, my next step is to produce diagnostic plots for each of the models, which I have not been able to figure out so far. If anyone could provide some direction for doing this that would be a nice bonus!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imap_dfr` from `purrr` :

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::imap_dfr(linear.models, ~broom::tidy(.x) %>% 
                                  mutate(Site = .y, .before = 'term'))
#.before is available in dplyr 1.0.0

# A tibble: 10 x 6
#   Site            term          estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#   <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Henderson Creek (Intercept)   3.25      1.27         2.56  0.0282  
# 2 Henderson Creek Date         -0.00165   0.000632    -2.61  0.0260  
# 3 Hobsonville     (Intercept)   0.155     1.54         0.100 0.921   
# 4 Hobsonville     Date         -0.000132  0.000769    -0.171 0.866   
# 5 Meola Reef      (Intercept) -10.5       1.85        -5.70  0.000199
# 6 Meola Reef      Date          0.00521   0.000921     5.65  0.000212
# 7 Shoal Bay       (Intercept)  -3.38      2.24        -1.51  0.157   
# 8 Shoal Bay       Date          0.00163   0.00112      1.46  0.169   
# 9 Whau River      (Intercept)  -0.852     2.14        -0.399 0.695   
#10 Whau River      Date          0.000375  0.00106      0.353 0.728
```

Or using base R functions with  `broom::tidy`.

```
data <- lapply(linear.models, broom::tidy)
output <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, Site = names(data), data))
rownames(output) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, your imap_dfr suggestion worked great. Are you aware of any benefit of using imap_dfr over nest, as suggested by @akrun?

Comment: @TarnD There is no one general case where one is better over other. It usually depends on the use case. Here we need names of the list so we use `imap_dfr` which passes names as well as data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `do`, we can `nest` and then `map` over the `list` 'data' to apply the `model`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
out <- annual.subset %>%
         group_by(Site) %>%
         nest %>%
         mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(BHMmetal.score~Date, data= .x)),
         output = map(model, tidy))


out %>% 
     select(Site, output) %>%
     unnest(c(output))
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Site [5]
#   Site            term          estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#   <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Hobsonville     (Intercept)   0.155     1.54         0.100 0.921   
# 2 Hobsonville     Date         -0.000132  0.000769    -0.171 0.866   
# 3 Henderson Creek (Intercept)   3.25      1.27         2.56  0.0282  
# 4 Henderson Creek Date         -0.00165   0.000632    -2.61  0.0260  
# 5 Meola Reef      (Intercept) -10.5       1.85        -5.70  0.000199
# 6 Meola Reef      Date          0.00521   0.000921     5.65  0.000212
# 7 Shoal Bay       (Intercept)  -3.38      2.24        -1.51  0.157   
# 8 Shoal Bay       Date          0.00163   0.00112      1.46  0.169   
# 9 Whau River      (Intercept)  -0.852     2.14        -0.399 0.695   
#10 Whau River      Date          0.000375  0.00106      0.353 0.728
```

---

In the OP's code the `data` specified in `lm` is a single dataset object `annual.df.subset` and thus we get the same output.  It would be `.`

```
annual.subset %>%
                   group_by(Site) %>%
                      do(model = lm(BHMmetal.score~Date, data=.)) %>%
                       tidy(model)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   Site [5]
#   Site            term          estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#   <chr>           <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 Henderson Creek (Intercept)   3.25      1.27         2.56  0.0282  
# 2 Henderson Creek Date         -0.00165   0.000632    -2.61  0.0260  
# 3 Hobsonville     (Intercept)   0.155     1.54         0.100 0.921   
# 4 Hobsonville     Date         -0.000132  0.000769    -0.171 0.866   
# 5 Meola Reef      (Intercept) -10.5       1.85        -5.70  0.000199
# 6 Meola Reef      Date          0.00521   0.000921     5.65  0.000212
# 7 Shoal Bay       (Intercept)  -3.38      2.24        -1.51  0.157   
# 8 Shoal Bay       Date          0.00163   0.00112      1.46  0.169   
# 9 Whau River      (Intercept)  -0.852     2.14        -0.399 0.695   
#10 Whau River      Date          0.000375  0.00106      0.353 0.728
```

#### data

```
annual.subset <- structure(list(Site = c("Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", 
"Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", 
"Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", 
"Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", "Hobsonville", 
"Hobsonville", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", 
"Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", 
"Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", "Henderson Creek", 
"Henderson Creek", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", 
"Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", 
"Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Meola Reef", "Shoal Bay", 
"Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", 
"Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", 
"Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Shoal Bay", "Whau River", "Whau River", 
"Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", 
"Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", 
"Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", "Whau River", 
"Whau River", "Whau River"), Date = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2015L, 2016L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L
), BHMmetal.score = c(-0.125, -0.092, -0.093, -0.123, -0.104, 
-0.102, -0.106, -0.101, -0.125, -0.105, -0.117, -0.157, -0.111, 
-0.098, -0.093, -0.087, -0.096, -0.104, -0.139, -0.047, -0.048, 
-0.059, -0.062, -0.055, -0.079, -0.04, -0.058, -0.072, -0.068, 
-0.067, -0.084, -0.103, -0.1, -0.102, -0.12, -0.094, -0.082, 
-0.1, -0.109, -0.083, -0.048, -0.031, -0.031, -0.081, -0.119, 
-0.12, -0.131, -0.098, -0.127, -0.118, -0.119, -0.125, -0.099, 
-0.083, -0.101, -0.094, -0.084, -0.089, -0.065, -0.07, -0.089, 
-0.093, -0.117, -0.127, -0.142, -0.124, -0.13, -0.092, -0.12, 
-0.083, -0.101, -0.112, -0.06, -0.074, -0.064, -0.102)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76"))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun, those solutions worked perfectly!
I'm aware there are usually multiple ways to achieve the same result in R, but wondered if you could give your opinion on when/why the `nest` approach might be better than the `do` approach?

Comment: @TamD `do` is an old method and it is slower, but `map` and other options are faster